# Expression/idiom for lecturing an expert as a novice

Tags: expressions

As in the title, I'm looking for an expression/idiom where a novice tries to lecture an expert on their field of expertise.

Comment: Well, "mansplaining" comes close.

Comment: That's a good specific example. Is there a more general term that comes to mind?

Comment: There are a number of metaphors (which don't come to mind just now), but single words are apt to be hard to find.

Answer (score 0):

> ***[teach grandmother to suck eggs](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/teach+grandmother+to+suck+eggs)***
>
> To try to teach an older person who is wiser and more experienced and
> worldly than a young person may think. *Why are you explaining basic
> typing to Ethel? Yes, she's 70, but she's been using a computer since
> before you were born—quit teaching your grandmother to suck eggs.*

Or, if you prefer:

> ***[teach fish how to swim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teach_fish_how_to_swim)***
>
> **Teach fish how to swim** is an idiomatic expression derived from the
> Latin proverb *piscem natare doces*. The phrase describes the
> self-sufficiency of those who know better how to do everything than
> the experts. It corresponds to the expression, "teaching grandmother
> to suck eggs".

There's also:

> ***I've forgotten more than you'll ever know***

but I am unable to find a reputable reference for it at the moment.