# What is a good idiom for telling someone something that they already know a lot about?

Tags: idiom-requests

Like when you're in a conversation with someone about something and you're telling them about XYZ, but it turns out they are already experts in the subject matter, an idiom like trying to teach the teacher.

Comment: *Teach fish how to swim*. But, if somebody tells you that *your* and *you are* are not the same, don't respond with this idiom!

Comment: @mahmud koya   Indeed, because this would be like teaching the deaf to hear.

Comment: and also [Idiom for explaining something to someone who clearly knows the topic (probably better than you)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/418731/idiom-for-explaining-something-to-someone-who-clearly-knows-the-topic-probably)

Comment: and also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/465018/expression-idiom-for-lecturing-an-expert-as-a-novice

Comment: I must say, "Teach fish how to swim" is not very current / not popular at all.  in both US / BR

Comment: This is NOT exactly what you're asking, but "taking coals to Newcastle" is a sort of similar thing.

Comment: Teaching a knight how to swing the sword?

Comment: Hi, @user186103. As you can see from the long list of potential duplicates, this is a common question! It's likely that your question will be closed as a duplicate of one of these other questions, but that isn't anything against your question—it will be kept so people looking for something similar who think about this more the way you do will have an easier time finding the information when they search. In the meantime, hopefully one of the answers attached to the linked question(s) will be helpful.

Answer (score 9):

***Teaching your grandmother to suck eggs*** is a classic.

[look it up in Wikipedia if you wish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teaching_grandmother_to_suck_eggs)

Answer (score 2):

One word for this concept with a lot of currency is [mansplaining.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/mansplaining-definition-history) It’s well-known  enough that I’ve even heard it humorously applied when a woman is doing it.

Comment: Wouldn't that be ma-amsplaining?